# How to dual boot Mac OS X and Ubuntu without rEFIt

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac, multi-boot, refit

I want to install Ubuntu on my Mac but I don't want have to use rEFIt. Can I do that? Can I just hold the control key on startup and use that to pick what I startup with? And if so would I install Ubuntu the same way just skipping the rEFIt part? Thanks. And I'm running Mac OS X 10.8.2

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done without installing the boot loader, unless you use virtualization instead.